# Table Layout isn't shown

Tags: android, dynamic, for-loop, tablelayout

I'm develop a dynamic table layout using java code

the first row is in xml

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/TableMain" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lTable11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="#C0C0C0"
                    android:text="Grade" 
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="#C0C0C0"
                    android:text="Hourse"
                    android:gravity="right" 
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:background="#C0C0C0"
                    android:text="Subject Name"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp" 
                      />

                    </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

the remain rows is in the java part which is have the same property in xml

```
TextView tvRowGrades[]=new TextView[gotSubName.length];
    TextView tvRowHourse[]=new TextView[gotSubName.length];
    TextView tvRowSubName[]=new TextView[gotSubName.length];

    TableRow row[]=new TableRow[gotGradeItem.length];
    LinearLayout LRow[]=new LinearLayout[gotGradeItem.length];
    tableMain=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableMain);

    for(int i=0;i<gotHourse.length;i++){
        row[i]=new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lRow=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lRow.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
        row[i].setLayoutParams(lRow);
        row[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLRow=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LRow[i]=new LinearLayout(this);
        LRow[i].setLayoutParams(lpLRow);
        LRow[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LRow[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        tvRowGrades[i]=new TextView(this);
        tvRowGrades[i].setText(gotGradeItem[i]);
        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpTvOther=new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2);
        lpTvOther.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tvRowGrades[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tvRowGrades[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tvRowGrades[i].setLayoutParams(lpTvOther);
        LRow[i].addView(tvRowGrades[i]);

        tvRowHourse[i]=new TextView(this);
        tvRowHourse[i].setText(gotHourse[i]+"");
        tvRowHourse[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tvRowHourse[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tvRowHourse[i].setLayoutParams(lpTvOther);
        LRow[i].addView(tvRowHourse[i]);

        tvRowSubName[i]=new TextView(this);
        tvRowSubName[i].setText(gotSubName[i]);
        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpTvSubName=new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 6);
        lpTvSubName.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tvRowSubName[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tvRowSubName[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tvRowSubName[i].setLayoutParams(lpTvSubName);
        LRow[i].addView(tvRowSubName[i]);

        row[i].addView(LRow[i]);
        tableMain.addView(row[i]);
    }
```

When i run the application the table is not displaying
please i want solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `TableRow` width to match_parent

```
           <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:background="#000000" >
```

The problem is that your row's width is defined by it's content (`wrap_content`), and your content's width (the `LinearLayout` that is inside the row) is defined by the parent.

You can also delete the `LinearLayout` and put the `TextView` items directly in the `TableRow` as it extends `LinearLayout`.

For the other rows that you add in the code you should also change the `LayoutParams`:

```
 TableRow.LayoutParams lRow=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: i change it and its display the first row xml
but the other dynamic rows in java doesnt appear

Comment: i changed the wrap_content in java code but it didnt appear any thing also I need the linear layout because the layout_Weight is apllying

Comment: can you see if the code inside the for loop same as the xml code arrangement

Comment: you should change the height of the TextView items to WRAP_CONTENT. and you can use weights inside a TableRow because a TableRow is also a LinearLayout.

Comment: i removed the linear Layour and it didn't apply the weight

Comment: well you should provide your updated code if you want to get help. Can you see the rows now?

Comment: this is before delete the linear https://www.dropbox.com/s/ylega5h8fa33ugn/1.png this is after delete it https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1z3nh1sgc924s7/2.png

Comment: can you help me in the good weights that's make text view "sub name" is bigger than the other text views